# WPF Programmatically Enable TextBox Scrolling/Panning for Tablets

Tags: c#, wpf, scroll, textbox, tablet

I am working with a WPF application that will be used on Windows tablets. The issue I am having is that I cannot scroll through a large multi-line TextBox on a tablet by pressing and dragging the content. However, it still scrolls on a desktop with a mouse wheel.

This question ([Enable swipe scrolling on Textbox control in WPF Scrollviewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26781833/enable-swipe-scrolling-on-textbox-control-in-wpf-scrollviewer)) seems to answer the same problem I am having, but I need to do it programmatically. This is what I am doing to set the panning mode of the TextBox:

```
txtLongText.SetValue(ScrollViewer.PanningModeProperty, PanningMode.None);
```

Which I can tell is working because the click & drag text selection is now disabled, but the content still does not scroll. I am also setting the panning mode of the outer ScrollViewer as such:

```
popupScrollView.PanningMode = PanningMode.Both;
```

The `popupScrollView` object is then being set as the content inside a Popup.

The only thing I can think of is if there is somewhere else higher up that I need to be setting the panning mode? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please add some code samples to replicate this issue.

Answer (score 1):

i have same problem with touch devices. i have a tricky way to handle this kind of issues

You have to handle touch event manually
i have written some codes to handle touch events manually

when `UIElement_OnTouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)` event occurred you can keep position of touched position by `eventArgs.GetTouchPoint(this).Position.Y`.

after that, you can determine is scroll happened or not by watching the position changes.

here is my sample [gist](https://gist.github.com/1saeedsalehi/75004c21c917033a94dd46c323032ea6)
, i use this approach for same issue with touch devices

Answer (score 1):

I think you require to use three properties to achieve this.

```
ScrollViewer.PanningMode
ScrollViewer.PanningDeceleration
ScrollViewer.PanningRatio
```

By default, `PanningMode` sets to `None`, but set it to another value will enable touch scrolling.

Another thing you can try is to set `ScrollViewer` `CanContentScroll` to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

While Im not sure there is a viable way to solve that using wpf only, I recommend trying to implement html UI inside your wpf application using DoNetBrowser, [link](https://dotnetbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000124840-%D0%9Dow-to-create-html-ui-for-wpf-application-using-dotnetbrowser).

Then you can use the textarea control in html, which in default lets you scroll on mobile.
Hope this answer helped you.